# How to use list of pages from graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

Tags: facebook, json, .net-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk, webforms

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USERS_AUTH_TOKEN
```

returns a list of pages the user has admin status in (in JSON format).

I would like to list all the pages in a dropdownlist, and make the user choose which facebook page he wants to use (on my webapp), so I can obtain the specific access token for that facebook page.

My question is - whats the easiest and best way to do that. Ive never worked with JSON before, but I guess theres a pretty easy was to do this through the facebook-sdk.

Comment: My first guess is that you make an WebRequest with the url, and use some fancy linq on the returned data to generate a List maybe. Specific c# code would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay figured out a way to do it. But I have no idea ifs the right way or the most optimal.
Would very much like inputs on it.

```
 [DataContract]
 internal class FacebookObj
 {
    [DataMember]
    public List<FacebookAccount> data;
    [DataMember]
    public FacebookNext paging;
 }   

    [DataContract]
    internal class FacebookAccount
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string name;
        [DataMember]
        public string category;
        [DataMember]
        public string id;
        [DataMember]
        public string access_token;
    }

    [DataContract]
    internal class FacebookNext
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string next;
    }

public void ShowPages(string authToken) {

 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=" + authToken);

            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            Stream sr = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

            if (sr != null)
            {
                jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FacebookObj));
                FacebookObj o = (FacebookObj)jsonSer.ReadObject(sr2);

                foreach (FacebookAccount s in o.data)
                {
                    //Do stuff
                    Response.Write(s.id + " - " + s.name + "<br />");
                }



            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the C# SDK, just take the array of objects and convert them into a `IList<IDictionary>()` array using the pageId as the key and the value being the page name.

This is not fully compilable, but you get the idea:

```
private void IList<IDictionary<long,string>> ConvertToList(dynamic meAccounts)
{

  foreach(var acc in meAccounts.data)
  {
    yield return new Dictionary((long)acc.id, (string)acc.name);
  }

{
```

Comment: Erhm. No sorry I dont get the idea really. I figured out a way to do it, but its soooo slow. Takes +30 secs to execute the damn thing. Maybe you have some inputs on it. Ill post it in a sec.